# Custom Bean Validation UnexpectedType Exception Spring 3.2

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I'm new into an application which uses Spring 3.2. Project is about an upgrade and we upgraded Java 1.6 to 1.7. After upgrading I'm facing an issue with the custom bean validation on the group of field.

I had Google and understand about the validation and it looks good. Please note this works with Java 1.6 very well and I made code comparison too.

Controller.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = Constants.URL, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView process(
            @ModelAttribute("Bean") Bean Bean,
            BindingResult result, SessionStatus status,
            @RequestParam(Constants.WIZARD_PAGE) int currentPage,
            ModelMap modelMap, Model model, Locale locale,
            RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {
isNotValid(Bean, result, Interface.class);
}

public boolean isNotValid(Object target, Errors errors, Class<?>... groups) {
        Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> result = validator.validate(target,
                groups);

Bean Class

    @NotEmpty
    @PhoneComposite(phone1 = "phone1", phone2 = "phone2", phone3 = "phone3", groups = {
            Interface.class, Interface2.class })
    private Phone phone = new Phone();

    Phone Bean Class

    public Phone() {
        super();
    }

    public Phone(String phone1, String phone2, String phone3) {
        this();
        this.phone1 = phone1;
        this.phone2 = phone2;
        this.phone3 = phone3;
    }

    //having getter and setter too
```

Constraint Class

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = { PhoneCompositeValidator.class })
@Documented
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface PhoneComposite {

    /**
     * Message.
     * 
     * @return the string
     */
    String message() default "{invalid.phone}";

    /**
     * Groups.
     * 
     * @return the class[]
     */
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    /**
     * Payload.
     * 
     * @return the class<? extends payload>[]
     */
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    /**
     * phone1.
     * 
     * @return the string
     */
    String phone1();

    /**
     * phone2.
     * 
     * @return the string
     */
    String phone2();

    /**
     * phone3.
     * 
     * @return the string
     */
    String phone3();

}

Validator Class

public class PhoneCompositeValidator  implements ConstraintValidator<PhoneComposite, Object>{

    /** The phone1 name. */
    private String phone1Name; 

    /** The phone2 name. */
    private String phone2Name; 

    /** The phone3 name. */
    private String phone3Name;

    /**
     * Initialize.
     *
     * @param arg0 the arg0
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(PhoneComposite arg0) {
        phone1Name = arg0.phone1() ;
        phone2Name = arg0.phone2() ;
        phone3Name = arg0.phone3() ;

    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see javax.validation.ConstraintValidator#isValid(java.lang.Object, javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext)
     */
    /**
     * Checks if is valid.
     *
     * @param arg0 the arg0
     * @param arg1 the arg1
     * @return true, if is valid
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Object arg0, ConstraintValidatorContext arg1) {
        String phone1 = null ;
        String phone2 = null ;
        String phone3 = null ;
        try {
            phone1 = BeanUtils.getProperty(arg0, phone1Name) ;
            if (StringUtils.isEmpty(phone1) || (!phone1.matches("\\d{3}"))) {
                LoggerService.error("Phone1 Not Valid");
                return false ;
            }
            phone2 = BeanUtils.getProperty(arg0, phone2Name) ;
            if (StringUtils.isEmpty(phone2) || (!phone2.matches("\\d{3}"))) {
                LoggerService.error("Phone2 Not Valid");
                return false ;
            }
            phone3 = BeanUtils.getProperty(arg0, phone3Name) ;
            if (StringUtils.isEmpty(phone3) || (!phone3.matches("\\d{4}"))) {
                LoggerService.error("Phone3 Not Valid");
                return false ;
            }
            return true ;
        }   catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace() ;
            return false;
        }

    } 

}
```

Usage of libraries

```
    <dependency org="javax.validation" name="validation-api" rev="1.0.0.GA" transitive="false">
         <artifact name="validation-api" ext="jar"/>
    </dependency>

    <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-api" rev="1.7.5" transitive="false">
         <artifact name="slf4j-api" ext="jar"/>
    </dependency>
    <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-log4j12" rev="1.7.5" transitive="false">
         <artifact name="slf4j-log4j12" ext="jar"/>
    </dependency>
```

Note: this is working in Java 1.6 and also no code change made for upgrade.

Exception:

```
Caused by: javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: No validator could be found for type bean.Phone. See: @Size at private bean.Phone bean.Bean.phone
at org.apache.bval.jsr303.AnnotationProcessor.checkOneType(AnnotationProcessor.java:328)
at org.apache.bval.jsr303.AnnotationProcessor.getConstraintValidator(AnnotationProcessor.java:303)
at org.apache.bval.jsr303.AnnotationProcessor.applyConstraint(AnnotationProcessor.java:243)
at org.apache.bval.jsr303.AnnotationProcessor.processAnnotation(AnnotationProcessor.java:151)
at org.apache.bval.jsr303.AnnotationProcessor.processAnnotations(AnnotationProcessor.java:92)
at org.apache.bval.jsr303.AnnotationProcessor.applyConstraint(AnnotationProcessor.java:279)
at org.apache.bval.jsr303.AnnotationProcessor.processAnnotation(AnnotationProcessor.java:151)
at org.apache.bval.jsr303.AnnotationProcessor.processAnnotations(AnnotationProcessor.java:92)
at org.apache.bval.jsr303.Jsr303MetaBeanFactory.processClass(Jsr303MetaBeanFactory.java:134)
at org.apache.bval.jsr303.Jsr303MetaBeanFactory.buildMetaBean(Jsr303MetaBeanFactory.java:95)
at org.apache.bval.MetaBeanBuilder.buildForClass(MetaBeanBuilder.java:129)
at org.apache.bval.MetaBeanManager.findForClass(MetaBeanManager.java:102)
at org.apache.bval.jsr303.ClassValidator.validate(ClassValidator.java:140)
at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.validate(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:199)
```

Please help me to find out which jar it might be referring on it dependency as I'm suspecting with some java version.

Comment: `@NotEmpty` is for strings/chars and arrays/collections only. Try removing it

Comment: @isah Really thanks a lot for your help...I appreciate and you saved me. It worked but can you explain why it works in 1.6 and failing in 1.7. Similarly annotation annotation Past also I removed for another date parameter it worked...can you please explain it